# How to create a map of Europe with the European part of Russia included in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot data of number of passengers from the Holland America Line. I created a shapefile with Eurostat, but Russia isn't included. The thing is, that I don't want a map with whole Russia, but only the European part like below.

[image]

Is there a shapefile available with only the "European" Part of Russia?

The dataset looks like this:

| region | Freq | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Austria | 7095 | AT |
| Belarus | 1 | BY |
| Belgium | 3 | BE |
| Croatia | 103 | HR |
| Czech Republic | 27 | CZ |
| France | 3374 | FR |
| Germany | 4132 | DE |
| Greece | 1 | GR |
| Hungary | 20 | HU |
| Italy | 2 | IT |
| Latvia | 34 | LV |
| Lithuania | 183 | LT |
| Luxembourg | 4 | LU |
| Netherlands | 29123 | NL |
| Poland | 2409 | PL |
| Romania | 171 | RO |
| Russia | 1469 | RU |
| Slovakia | 1 | SK |
| Switzerland | 4 | CH |
| Ukraine | 60 | UK |

With the following code I managed to create a map of Europe, excluding Russia. But, is there a possibility to get the geometrics of the Europe part of Russia?

```
# Get geometrics
Europe_shp <- get_eurostat_geospatial(resolution = 10, 
                                      nuts_level = 0, 
                                      year = 2016)
                                      
# Merge passenger data data with geometrics
European_Countries_1907 <- merge(country_passengers_1907_europe_code, Europe_shp, all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE, by.x = "ID", by.y = "id")

# Create plot of Europe
vector_colors_gradient_2 <- c("#fff997", "#ffd983", "#ffb97b", "#f89b79","#e6807c", "#cd6a80", "#ad5983", "#874c82", "#5d427b", "#2b386f")

Map_1907 <- European_Countries_1907 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = log10(Freq))) +
  aes(geometry = geometry) +
  geom_sf(size = 0.1, color = "#F3F3F3") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = vector_colors_gradient_2,
                       labels = ~scales::comma(10^.x)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-10, 27)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(33, 70)) +
  labs(
    title = "Travellers from Europe",
    subtitle = "Number of HAL Passengers in 1907",
    caption = "Data: Stadsarchief Rotterdam",
    fill = "Number of Passengers"
  ) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(20, 0, 20, 20))
Map_1907
```

Comment: interesting question. I really like the rnaturalearth package which might contain shapefiles for those respective regions. Or this link might help https://www.igismap.com/download-russia-shapefile-free-country-map-administrative-divisions/

Comment: another option would be, of course, to simply limit your coordinates (e.g., https://rpubs.com/mkollontai/DATA607_TidyVerse) - this would also come closer to your example graph

Comment: Limiting the coordinates seems to work perfectly. The only thing I still don't know how to do is to get a colored map based on passenger frequency. So, to fill the countries based on the frequency of a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As tjebo says, the rnaturalearth package is a great source of geographic data. You can get the entire world as a shapefile and perform a left join with your own data. Replicating the map above requires plotting with crs set to EPSG 3035 and appropriate axis limits:

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

world <- ne_countries(scale = 50, returnclass = 'sf')

ggplot(world) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = continent), color = 'black') +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = name), size = 5) +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(3035),
           xlim = c(2000000, 6200000), 
           ylim = c(1500000, 5500000)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#c4c0a0', NA, '#c9cc3d', '#fcd752', 
                               NA, NA, NA, NA), guide = 'none', 
                    na.value = 'white') +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = '#92c5f0'),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(linewidth = 0.1, 
                                        color = '#80808080'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have one more question, how can I use the fill Aesthetic to get a Choropleth map with colors based on number of passenger frequency?

Comment: @EwoudBrouwer instead of using `aes(fill = name)` you would have `aes(fill = Freq)` and remove the `scale_fill_manual`. You can use one of the other `scale_fill_` functions to provide you with a gradient color scale for your choropleth map. (The default one is a rather dull blue scale)

Comment: very nice, as usual, Allan

Comment: It worked by adding aes(geometry = geometry) to the ggplot object. Thanks anyway.